# In msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail, @profile_name is not valid

Tags: sql-server, email, sp-send-dbmail

I use a SQL Server job to execute `SendEmail` stored procedure. The job is working fine when the `@recipients` is our specified email address.

Since I couldn't log into our specified email address to check whether the email has been received, I want to change `@recipients` as my email address

The question is when I make this changed, the job history shows this job is not executed. The error is

> Profile_name is not valid

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Here is the example.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_email 
@profile_name = 'ISSS Group',
@recipients = 'isss@xxx.edu',
@body = @mess,--@mess is a table
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject = 'Student Information Update',
@from_address = 'administration@xxx.edu';
```

I want to change `@recipients = 'isss@xxx.edu'` to `@recipients = 'myemail@xxx.edu'`to check whether the email has been received. But once I change it, the SQL Server job is failed. The error shows

> Profile name is not valid.

Comment: Please show an example of code that causes the error.

Comment: Sure, I just update the question.

Comment: Thanks. Could we also see the output of the queries `select * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile;
select * from msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount;`. I presume you have not intentionally changed the profile name from what was in the original SP? It should still be valid if the SP still works with it.

Comment: I am really sorry that I can't share the real case. But I execute your queries. From the first query, the profile name does not have  "ISSS Group". Could your explain your concerns?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the name of a registered profile; you can't make them up on-the-fly.

However, I assume you want a different display name, hence why you seem to be trying to change it by renaming the profile.

You would either need to create a new profile for the new name, or simply pass it in at runtime. The format for this is:

```
@from_address = 'Displayed Name <emailaddress@example.com>'
```

So, for example,

```
@from_address = 'ISSS Group <administration@xxx.edu>'
```

I use this method, and it might do everything you need here. Whether there is any benefit to setting up an entirely separate profile, I don't know; you would have to research that further.